# Is posible to get Beacon advert in IOS without using the 0x004c Apple Company Identifier

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon, ios-bluetooth

I have developed an Android app in order to get data from a iBeacon, as I could get the raw data I had no problems doing it, but in IOS it is not posible and it seems as if it was no posible to receive packets which don't have Apple Company Identifier 0x004c into the advert. Is posible to receive adverts from devices which advert using other Company Identifiers?
If it is posible, would be posible to receive the Company Identifier code?
I wasn't able to find anything in the documentation provided by Apple or searching in several forums.

Any idea will be really welcome.

The sniffer capture the following:

Nordic Semiconductors' Company Identifier:

```
+----------------------------------------------------+----------------- - - -
|     Packet sniffer frame header                    |
+----+-------------+-------------------------+-------+
|info| Packet nbr. | Time stamp              | Length|  Packet data
+----+-------------+-------------------------+-------+----------------- - - -
| 01 | 0C 00 00 00 | 49 12 27 44 00 00 00 00 | 30 00 | 2F D6 BE 89 8E 40 24 4E A0 C3 8B 04 FF 02 01 04 1A FF 59 00 02 15 01 12 23 34 45 56 67 78 89 9A AB BC CD DE EF F0 00 01 00 01 BB BA 88 BA 37 A5
+----+-------------+-------------------------+-------+----------------- - - -
```

Apple's Company Identifier:

```
+----------------------------------------------------+----------------- - - -
|     Packet sniffer frame header                    |
+----+-------------+-------------------------+-------+
|info| Packet nbr. | Time stamp              | Length|  Packet data
+----+-------------+-------------------------+-------+----------------- - - -
| 01 | 01 00 00 00 | ED 07 68 00 00 00 00 00 | 30 00 | 2F D6 BE 89 8E 40 24 E4 98 E6 3C 1B 5D 02 01 1A 1A FF 4C 00 02 15 01 12 23 34 45 56 67 78 89 9A AB BC CD DE EF F0 00 00 00 00 C5 E8 19 24 3A A5
+----+-------------+-------------------------+-------+----------------- - - -
```

Regards

Iván

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible to read the raw bytes of a beacon advertisement in iOS using `CoreBluetooth` or otherwise access the company code or other fields.  You can only get the fields provided by `CoreLocation`, basically the three part beacon identifier.  See here: http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2013/10/21/corebluetooth-doesnt-let-you-see-ibeacons.html

Experimentation shows that `CoreLocation` APIs will only detect beacon advertisements with a company code of 0x00ff or less -- the most significant byte must be zero.

Comment: I had read it before and yes, it seems it is not posible to get data from iBeacons with other company identifiers. Apple wants to lock its devices. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: davidgyoung, one question, so if I use a 0x0000 company code, the app iBeacon Locate would detect the device? Because I tried it and it only works when I set the Apple's one 0x004c, otherwise there is no beacon is found. I show an example of advert sniffer capture:

Comment: Bluetooth packet using Nordic Semiconductors' Company Identifier:
|info| Packet nbr. | Time stamp              | Length|  Packet data
| 01 | 0C 00 00 00 | 49 12 27 44 00 00 00 00 | 30 00 | 2F D6 BE 89 8E 40 24 4E A0 C3 8B 04 FF 02 01 04 1A FF 59 00 02 15 01 12 23 34 45 56 67 78 89 9A AB BC CD DE EF F0 00 01 00 01 BB BA 88 BA 37 A5

Bluetooth packet using Apple's Company Identifier:
| 01 | 01 00 00 00 | ED 07 68 00 00 00 00 00 | 30 00 | 2F D6 BE 89 8E 40 24 E4 98 E6 3C 1B 5D 02 01 1A 1A FF 4C 00 02 15 01 12 23 34 45 56 67 78 89 9A AB BC CD DE EF F0 00 00 00 00 C5 E8 19 24 3A A5

Comment: Sorry, I really cannot comment further on the details of the iBeacon advertising format since it is proprietary.

Comment: No problem! Thanks anyway. As far as I know there is no way of getting adverts  without the Apple's Company Identifier, at least I am not able to. Regards

Answer (score -1):

Instead CoreLocation try to use the CoreBluetooth Framework.

You should have all the BLE information here:

```
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI.
```

Comment: Your idea is good, but as davidgoung said in the first answer it seems as if it is not posible to get those adverts, and if you use the CoreBluetooth Framework you will be only able to get the UUID and nothing else. My idea was to get the Id Identifier, Major and Minor from a specific UUID.